# How to draw a properly aligned Rectangle inside Irregular Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, rectangles, quadrilateral

My real life problem is that I am tiling my 12' x 10' room floor which is in the shape of an Irregular Quadrilateral and I want to draw black tile border 4" width and approx. 1 foot away from walls, so far my markings are based on guess work and I am afraid I will end up making a tilted border (as shown in fig 2).

Therefore I would like to know if there is any formula or way to make a properly aligned rectangle inside Irregular Quadrilateral.

As I try to draw in fig 1 (again it is created using guess work) but it was easy in small space like this but for large space I have no idea.

---

[image]

---

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not yet a precise mathematical problem, and so does not have a clear answer. Perhaps this might be a reformulation: Find the orientation of the interior rectangle that minimizes the sum of the absolute values of the four angular deviations between the rectangle's sides and the quarilateral's side. For example, the right quad side in Fig.1 is $7^\circ$ off from vertical.

Comment: So you want it to be parallel to the top edge, not to the right edge?

Comment: @Djura Marinkov NO, Actually thats the problem I can't be parallel to any edge because none of the edge is at right angle I just want to make sure that my square is centered and not tilted right or left

Comment: @Joseph I think we need to first find maximum-area-rectangle inside an irregular Quadrilateral

Comment: start from the vertex with the biggest angle and draw a rectangle, as large as you can